# calendar day/month/week view in android

Tags: android, android-calendar

I need an android calendar view like attached photo. I already tried with this library
    https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View for calendar view. 
    this one is fixed static event in calendar adding only.
    I could not add dynamically event in this library calendar view.
    can anybody suggest any custom library in android.

[image]

sample Android-Week-View for calendar view library code :

what I have tried in this library :

This is code , statically adding event in calendar view. when run this example, I can able to see the event at particular date in calendar view.

```
 @Override
 public List<WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {

  // Populate the week view with some events.
    List<WeekViewEvent> events = new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();

    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth-1);
    startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, newYear);
    Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
    endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth-1);
    WeekViewEvent event = new    WeekViewEvent(1, getEventTitle(startTime),
    startTime, endTime);
    event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_01));
    events.add(event);
      return events;
    }
    when i click this event on calendar page, its showing that event
    time and date in toast.
     @Override
    public void onEventClick(WeekViewEvent event, RectF eventRect) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked " 
    + event.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v("heal", "Clicked "+ event.getName()) ;
   }
```

Note :

- I need to add the same event in this calendar view dynamically.
- I don't know how to add this event.
- I just add one event inside `onCreate()`. But, that event is not showing in  calendar view  but, values are passing to that constructor. Can anybody help me to come out this.

Comment: Please add more information about what exactly you need. Because image don't display clearly your request.

Comment: "can anybody suggest any custom library in android." asking for library, tools etc is off-topic on StackOverflow, regardless opened bounty:  *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: Hi Sergy, can you see this app screen shots https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alamkanak.seriesaddict

Comment: Hi @harikrishnan, we are happy to help you, but we cannot understand what you require yet. Could you please explain better? Do you need a library which can add/delete/update events?

Comment: Go to android-arsenal.com you probably have something there, asking for a library on StackOverflow isn't the "best practice" like @SergeyShustikov said.

Comment: Hi All, i using this library, but i want the calendar should starts from 9AM to 6PM.....please help me out on this

Comment: Anyone knows how can add month view in this library

Answer (score 3):

The [library you are using](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View) supports dynamic event adding. Check [this sample](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View/issues/18) to get a better idea.

Comment: i using this library, but i want the calendar should starts from 9AM to 6PM.....can u please help me out on this

Comment: Android Week View is perfect for what you are trying to do. The only problem is that it doesn't support accessibility

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one it adds an event when a user clicks on an empty box. You can modify the parameters of the event as you wish.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WeekView.EventClickListener,WeekView.EmptyViewClickListener, MonthLoader.MonthChangeListener {

WeekView mWeekView;
List<WeekViewEvent> events;
Calendar clickedTime;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWeekView=findViewById(R.id.weekView);
    mWeekView.setAccessibilityLiveRegion(MODE_APPEND);
    mWeekView.setNumberOfVisibleDays(7);

    events= new ArrayList<WeekViewEvent>();
    clickedTime=Calendar.getInstance();

    // Lets change some dimensions to best fit the view.
    mWeekView.setColumnGap((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    mWeekView.setTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    mWeekView.setEventTextSize((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));

    mWeekView.setMonthChangeListener(this);
    mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(this);
    mWeekView.setOnEventClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public List<? extends WeekViewEvent> onMonthChange(int newYear, int newMonth) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "newMonth: "+newMonth+"  newYear: "+newYear, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Calendar startTime = (Calendar) clickedTime.clone();
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    startTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, newMonth);
    startTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, newYear);
    Calendar endTime = (Calendar) startTime.clone();
    endTime.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    WeekViewEvent event = new WeekViewEvent(1, "Event Name", startTime, endTime);
    //event.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.event_color_02));
    events.add(event);
    return events;
}

@Override
public void onEmptyViewClicked(final Calendar time) {
    clickedTime=(Calendar) time.clone();
    mWeekView.notifyDatasetChanged();
    Log.i("msg","Empty box has been filled successfully.");
}
}
```